# chrome doesn't display innerHTML changes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am creating a game of Boggle using an external javascript page to create the arrays. The problem I am having is

1. Chrome doesn't display the letters without creating a button to display them separately.
2. As the user enters words, the words are not displaying until the user quits the game.

It works fine on Firefox but I want it to work in Chrome too.

Any suggestions?

```js
function words(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      var word = new Array("balte", "table", "hat", "tab", "belt", "lab", "eat", "tea", "ate", "tale", "bale", "let", "bet", "teal", "late", "beat");
      break;
    case 2:
      var word = new Array("atwre", "water", "wet", "wear", "tear", "war", "ret", "rate", "eat", "ate", "tea", "awe", "raw", "rat", "wart", "art", "tar");
      break;
    case 3:
      var word = new Array("dclaen", "can", "cane", "and", "clan", "lane", "lean", "lend", "land", "den", "dean", "dance", "lance", "clean", "deal", "ale", "dale", "candle", "clad");
      break;
    case 4:
      var word = new Array("aepinlar", "air", "airplane", "plane", "plan", "lane", "lean", "pane", "ear", "near", "nap", "nape", "lair", "pen", "pan", "ape", "leap", "ale", "peal", "nap", "rap", "par", "pare", "pale", "are", "rail", "ail", "pail", "nail", "air", "pair", "ran", "pin", "pine", "line", "nip", "rip", "ripe", "lip", "earn", "learn", "ire");
      break;
    case 5:
      var word = new Array("redykboa", "keyboard", "key", "board", "bored", "bore", "bark", "dark", "dork", "oar", "boar", "ark", "dare", "bare", "are", "red", "rod", "road", "bode", "rode", "ode", "bread", "read", "bead", "bred", "break", "drey", "day", "boy", "broke", "rake", "bake", "ear", "dear", "bear", "dye", "dyer", "doer", "oak", "boa", "doe", "okay", "dab", "bade", "ade", "drake", "bard", "yard", "year", "beak", "beard", "bad", "bed", "bay");
      break;
  }
  return word;
}

compWords = new Array();
notAword = new Array();
playWords = new Array();

function displayLetters() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  compWords = words(num);
  yourWord = compWords[0];
  document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = yourWord;
}

function displayEntries() {
  document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = playWords.toString();
}

function boggle() {
  var play = "";
  var score = 0;
  var flag = 0;

  //get player entries
  while (play != "Q") {
    play = prompt("enter a word or enter Q when done");
    playWords.push(play);
    if (play != "Q")
      //document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = playWords.toString();
      displayEntries();
  }

  // check winning score and list bad words
  var complgth = compWords.length;
  var playlgth = (playWords.length - 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < playlgth; i++) {
    flag = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < complgth; k++) {
      if (playWords[i] == compWords[k]) {
        score++;
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
      notAword.push(playWords[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Your score is " +
    score + ". The following entries " +
    "are not valid words: <br />" +
    notAword.toString());
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000040;
  color: #88ffff;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 700px;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #88FFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #88FFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: medium groove #88FFFF;
  line-height: 135%;
}

.floatright {
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 0px 20px;
}

#footer {
  font-size: .60em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px double #000040;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #88ffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 1px none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h3 {
  color: #88ffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

.details {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 3700px;
  width: 500px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #88FFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000040;
  background-color: #88ffff;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono;
  color: #88ffff;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

td {
  border: 2px solid #88ffff;
  width: 5em;
  color: #88ffff;
}

.nobdr {
  border: none;
  cell-padding: 5px;
}

.OK {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Greg's Gambits | Greg's Game of Boggle</title>
  <link href="greg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="gregBoggle.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="images/superhero.jpg" width="120" height="120" class="floatleft" />
    <h1 align="center"><em>Greg's Game of Boggle</em></h1>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="nav">
      <p><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="greg.html">About</a>
        <a href="play_games.html">Play a Game</a>
        <a href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>The object of the game is to create as many words as you can, in a given time limit, from the letters show below. When you are ready to begin, click the Diplay letters button, then Begin game button.</p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Display letters" onclick="displayLetters();" /></p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Begin the game" onclick="boggle();" /></p>

      <h2><br /><br />Letters you can use:<br />
        <div id="letters">&nbsp;</div><br /></h2>
      <h2>Your words so far: <br />
        <div id="entries">&nbsp;</div><br /></h2>
      <h2>Results:<br />
        <div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2013 Greg's Gambits<br />
      <a href="mailto:foulksy@gmail.com">foulksy@gmail.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is `words` a function instead of just a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">` was introduced two decades ago to easy the pain of migration from HTML 3.2 and presentational HTML to semantic HTML and CSS. Since then we've have HTML 4.01, XHTML, and now HTML 5. Browsers use that Doctype as a clue to indicate that your code is designed to work on browsers of the IE 4 era and emulate a number of bugs from that time. You should write modern HTML.

Comment: All I can say is this is the way I was instructed to do it. Book is 5 years old and hasn't been updated to reflect current JavaScript or HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Mishelbi — The book was horribly out of date when it was published then. Find some better learning resources.

Comment: I agree with you. I have complained to the school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers aren't required to render DOM changes until the script finishes and returns to the main event loop. Firefox also does this when you call `prompt()`, but I don't think this is required.

Instead of using a `while` loop, you should use an input element that the user fills in. You can then use an event listener to read the input and update the DOM. This will work in all browsers.

Comment: How does one specify updating the DOM?

Comment: I have a problem where the following script doesn't update what's visually displayed: `        <script>
            i = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotations.length);
            p = document.getElementById("quotation");
            p.InnerHTML = quotations[i];
        </script>`

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer That should work if `getElementById()` returns the element successfully. Please post a new question with a [mcve].